# Unable to animate with transform functions

Tags: css, flexbox, css-animations

I've been trying to animate my image with almost all transform functions without success.

After googling it appeared that setting `with: auto` might be the cause.

But removing it from my style doesn't change anything at all. Still no animation.

Here you have my code :

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: auto;
  transition: scale-me 1.5s ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes scale-me {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="../images/Green-Monster-8-icon-128.png" class="logo" />
  </div>
</body>
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `animation` instead of `transition`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: auto;
  animation: scale-me 1.5s ease-in;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes scale-me {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="logo" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Unbelievable. It worked. I feel so stupid. This cold must have taken a huge toll on me. Anyway thank you @IvanS95

Comment: No problem @Bradzer small things like these are the most common problems for me as well lol